# how to get pickle to spacy binary

Tags: spacy

before spacy v3 I've been using pickle to store my data:

```
train_data.append((text, {'entities': labeled_entities}))
// [..]
pickle.dump(train_data, open('train_data.pkl', 'wb'))
```

with spacy v3 one should use the new config system.

```
--paths.train ./train.spacy --paths.dev ./dev.spacy
```

I understand that `--paths.train` is my test data (which I have as pickle), but what is `--paths.dev`?

Also how do I get my pickle data into .spacy binary format?

Comment: `--paths.dev` is the path to the validation (also called "tuning") data. Before creating a model, your data should be split into training and validation. And some also save a chunk for testing (unseen data).

Comment: Alse, see https://spacy.io/usage/training